# How to set active class one group element from other group based index in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two different kind of group. Each group having the same amount of items. The second group some elements having the some different updates. How set active class to first group element based on second group updated items,

Here is the my result how it will display,

```
<div id="numberOfProjects">
      <div class="projectListTrigger">
        <a href="#">1</a>
        <a href="#">2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="projectListTrigger">
        <a href="#">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="updateAvailable">4</a>
        <a href="#">5</a>
      </div>
      <div class="projectListTrigger">
        <a href="#">6</a>
        <a href="#">7</a>
        <a href="#">8</a>
        <a href="#" class="updateAvailable">9</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainSection">
      <div class="mainSectionItem">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainSectionItem">
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4 <div class="update">update</div></div>
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainSectionItem">
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9 <div class="update">update</div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the js,

```
var $currentUpdate = $('.update').parents('#mainSection > div > div').index('#mainSection > div > div');
    $('#numberOfProjects a').each(function(){
        $(this).eq($currentUpdate).addClass('updateAvailable');
    });
```

Comment: have you tried your self to write code?

Comment: ok then add that code in question .or create fiddle for better understand

Comment: Check my question @NishitMaheta

Comment: To clarify; You want to add a class of "updateAvailable" to the `<a>` tags in the "projectListTrigger" `<div>`s where there is a matching div with a class of "update" in the "mainSectionItem" `<div>`s?

Comment: If you go through my html, you will understand what i'm asking? @MrBearding

Comment: @Sathya check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8cLx11xj/

Comment: Thanks @NishitMaheta

Comment: @Sathya Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8cLx11xj/5/)

```
$('.update').each(function(){
   $('.projectListTrigger')
     .eq($(this).parents('.mainSectionItem').index())
     .find('a')
     .eq($(this).parent().index())
     .addClass('updateAvailable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like the below.

```js
var mainSectionArray = $('.mainSectionItem');

mainSectionArray.each(function() {
  var msa = $(this);
  var msaIndex = msa.index();

  msa.children().each(function() {
    var msaChild = $(this);
    if (msaChild.children('div').hasClass('update')) {
      $('.projectListTrigger').eq(msaIndex).children().eq(msaChild.index()).addClass('updateAvailable');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.updateAvailable {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numberOfProjects">
  <div class="projectListTrigger"> <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>

  </div>
  <div class="projectListTrigger"> <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>

  </div>
  <div class="projectListTrigger"> <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
    <a href="#">9</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="mainSection">
  <div class="mainSectionItem">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainSectionItem">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4
      <div class="update">update</div>
    </div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainSectionItem">
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9
      <div class="update">update</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: It looks like Nishit Maheta's answer may be more efficient, as my code iterates through each div, whereas Nishit's only iterates through the necessary elements.